# Update SDL1.2 SDL_GetWMInfo to SDL2 SDL_GetWindowWMInfo

Tags: sdl-2, sdl-1.2

I'm trying to update some C++ code in a custom version of DOSBox from SDL1.2 to SDL2. The lines that have me baffled are these:

```
SDL_SysWMinfo systemInfo; 
SDL_VERSION(&systemInfo.version);

if(SDL_GetWindowWMInfo(window, &systemInfo) !=1) return;
if (!::OpenClipboard(systemInfo.info.win.window)) return;
```

SDL_GetWindowWMInfo is defined in SDL_syswm.h this way:

```
typedef struct SDL_SysWMinfo SDL_SysWMinfo;
extern DECLSPEC SDL_bool SDLCALL SDL_GetWindowWMInfo(SDL_Window * window, SDL_SysWMinfo * info);
```

When I try to build in Visual Studio 2010, I get this error, thrown by the third line in the code above:

```
1>  sdlmain.cpp
1>..\src\gui\sdlmain.cpp(2966): error C2065: 'window' : undeclared identifier
```

I think the answer is here:

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/82068/how-can-i-obtain-a-window-handle-in-sdl-2-0-3

but I'm a beginner and can't figure out how to adapt that to my own code. If anyone is willing to help out a complete beginner, I'll be grateful.

Comment: What was unclear about [the wiki page for `SDL_GetWindowWMInfo()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowWMInfo)?

Comment: @emendelson you don't make linebreak in comments, but you can edit your own question to include additional information. "Curly red inderscore" doesn't describe anything, what is actual error message? Where (and how) your `window` is defined? (and of corse you can't use anything that is not declared)

Comment: I've rewritten my question with things I've learned since. Thanks again for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by adding the first line (as it explains clearly in the SDL wiki):

```
SDL_Window* window;
SDL_SysWMinfo systemInfo; 
SDL_VERSION(&systemInfo.version);

if(SDL_GetWindowWMInfo(window, &systemInfo) !=1) return;
if (!::OpenClipboard(systemInfo.info.win.window)) return;
```

Comment: Passing invalid (even worse, uninitialised) `window` is a really bad idea, as at least x11 implementation actually uses window data (haven't checked others; whouldn't be surprised if they do too). This is not what wiki page suggested. Pass actual window you've created and going to use.

Comment: Thank you for this - I'm merely modifying someone else's code, and am grateful to get ideas about how to improve it.

Comment: If you're drawing with SDL you're creating window somewhere with `SDL_CreateWindow`. This *is* the window that should be passed to `SDL_GetWindowWMInfo`, not something undefined.

Comment: I don't pretend to understand the code that I'm modifying, but I think it's doing this: The code is designed to paste the Windows clipboard into the DOSBox keyboard buffer. The lines I've been asking about seem to be asking if there's a window open to paste into.

Comment: Don't know with so little code. If that is the case, you can just pass NULL to `OpenClipboard` without need of getting HWND from SDL. I'm generally against "mess it up until it breaks and see what happens" approach, but I guess you have to experiment on something.